# android how to work with popups in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, popup

I am working with a mediaplayerApp. There I want to customize my screen for better UI.
In my app all list of songs i putted into a listview and below of listview seekbar is there for playing the song along with Play & Stop buttons are there.

I want to put all these means SeekBar, Play & Stop buttons into a Popup and that Popup should be placed at buttom of activity. When I select any song from listview at that time popup will visible otherwise it should invisible.

Is it possible?
If yes give me a way.
Thank you.